# JPA oneToMany with List and JoinTable

Tags: java, list, jpa, one-to-one

I am having a Tournament class and a Member class.

Only tournament has members (that is the information that I need) so in the tournament class I have:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
        cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinTable(name = "tournament_players", 
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tournament_id", nullable=false)},
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="member_id", nullable=false)})
List<Member> players;
```

The ids are auto generated integers.

When I have only one tournament everything its ok when I set the members.

If a I add a member already existed in tournament 1 to tournament 2 then I get a constraint violation which is correct from what I have read.

```
 Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_9JMTVNIY5RJ4A9S9XCI40NQGJ_INDEX_9 ON PUBLIC.TOURNAMENT_PLAYERS(TOURNAMENT_ID)
```

My question is what is the proper solution to my problem?

Comment: try this >> http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToMany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you really need is `ManyToMany` relationship.

Because in your case, one `Tournament` can have many `Member`(s), and `Member` can follow many `Tournament`(s).

If you use `OneToMany`, the JPA provider will check if the `Member` already has `Tournament` assigned, and will fail to add if it true

Comment: but does it matter that I do not want to have a reference from Member to Tournament? How I avoid having multiple lines of the same Member to the same Tournament?

Comment: hibernate? dont see that in the OP

Comment: @BillyFrost oh yeah, thanks for pointed that out. Edited to JPA provider :).

@Manos you need to have a `@JoinTable` to mapping `Tournament` and `Member` each other

Comment: Here `CascadeType.REFRESH` was wrong. Is `PERSIST` really enough? Not maybe `ALL`?